# How to grep selected strings separated by -

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am new in grep and I have a list of packages where I only need to display certain results.

Here's a list of packages:

```
apache2/oldoldstable,oldoldstable,now 2.4.25-3+deb9u12 amd64 [installed]
apache2-bin/oldoldstable,oldoldstable,now 2.4.25-3+deb9u12 amd64 [installed,automatic]
apache2-data/oldoldstable,oldoldstable,now 2.4.25-3+deb9u12 all [installed,automatic]
apache2-dbg/oldoldstable,oldoldstable 2.4.25-3+deb9u12 amd64
apache2-dev/oldoldstable,oldoldstable 2.4.25-3+deb9u12 amd64
apache2-doc/oldoldstable,oldoldstable 2.4.25-3+deb9u12 all
apache2-ssl-dev/oldoldstable,oldoldstable 2.4.25-3+deb9u12 amd64
apache2-suexec-custom/oldoldstable,oldoldstable 2.4.25-3+deb9u12 amd64
apache2-suexec-pristine/oldoldstable,oldoldstable 2.4.25-3+deb9u12 amd64
apache2-utils/oldoldstable,oldoldstable,now 2.4.25-3+deb9u12 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

I've been trying to use regex but I'm sure that there's something wrong:

```
cat list | grep 'apache2-(bin|data|utils)'
```

Here's my expected output:

```
apache2/oldoldstable,oldoldstable,now 2.4.25-3+deb9u12 amd64 [installed]
apache2-bin/oldoldstable,oldoldstable,now 2.4.25-3+deb9u12 amd64 [installed,automatic]
apache2-data/oldoldstable,oldoldstable,now 2.4.25-3+deb9u12 all [installed,automatic]
apache2-utils/oldoldstable,oldoldstable,now 2.4.25-3+deb9u12 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

What is wrong/missing in my command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the parenthesis and the `|` characters when using BRE (Basic Regular Expression) pattern matching which is the default in the [`grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep), so:

```
grep '^apache2-\?\(bin\|data\|utils\|\)/'
```

or enable the ERE (Extended Regular Expression) pattern matching with `-E` switch:

```
grep -E '^apache2-?(bin|data|utils|)/'
```

Notes:

- you don't need feed `grep` with `cat` as it reads from the file directly like many other tools.
- I added start-of-line `^` to start match from the beginning of the line.
- I added `-?` in ERE and `-\?` in BRE that matches on hyphen `-` zero-or-one time only; Also note that the use of `\?` isn't valid standard BRE (even though it works in at least GNU and maybe some other tools). The BRE equivalent of `\?` would be `\{0,1\}`.
- I added an empty last `|` match within `(...|...|...|)` that it will match on cases like lines with `apache2` only (but it will also match on `apache2-` if there was any in your input, if you don't want to match on that, use `grep -E '^apache2(-(bin|data|utils)|)/'` instead);
- Using `\|` is also not standard BRE, and there's no equivalent to it. Better to just use the ERE given alternative.

see also [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](/q/119905/72456)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
`grep -Ex 'apache2(-(bin|data|utils))?' list`

Output:

```
apache2
apache2-bin
apache2-data
apache2-utils
```

Oops, the question changed :).

`grep -E 'apache2(|/|(-(bin|data|utils)))?([^-]|$)' list`

Output:

```
apache2/oldoldstable,oldoldstable,now 2.4.25-3+deb9u12 amd64 [installed]
apache2-bin/oldoldstable,oldoldstable,now 2.4.25-3+deb9u12 amd64 [installed,automatic]
apache2-data/oldoldstable,oldoldstable,now 2.4.25-3+deb9u12 all [installed,automatic]
apache2-utils/oldoldstable,oldoldstable,now 2.4.25-3+deb9u12 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

-x (exactly match) not needed then.

You can use egrep instead of -E switch.
`egrep 'apache2(|/|(-(bin|data|utils)))?([^-]|$)' list`

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but I updated my question (my bad).

Comment: While that works, it might be helpful to explain why / what it does, so that every reader doesn't need to explicitly go out to read the man page to find out what `-x` and `-E` do.